# Can I create custom Entity Metadata Wrapper implementation for my custom entity type?

Tags: 7, entities

Basic usage of EMW is like:

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper($entity, 'entity_type');
$value = $wrapper->field_name->value();
```

Can I create EMW subclass for usage like this?:

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper($entity, 'entity_type');
$value = $wrapper->getFieldName();
//similar for setter
```

Comment: Yes, you can write and use whatever class you like, and that class can extend from whatever other class you like. Do you have a Drupal-related question?

Comment: @Clive unfortunately probably no in that case, I've read Entity code and in 'entity_metadata_wrapper' function is 'return new EntityDrupalWrapper($type, $data, $info);'. So the only option is to use Decorator pattern. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Oh, do you mean actually swap out the underlying class the function returns? If so then no, I would guess you're stuck with something unsatisfying unless you patch the module. There's no hint of DI in there. Might be safest just to roll your own version of the function and use that, even though it's awkward